# Windowing with Apache Beam - Fixed Windows Don't Seem to be Closing?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We are attempting to use fixed windows on an Apache Beam pipeline (using `DirectRunner`). Our flow is as follows:

1. Pull data from pub/sub
2. Deserialize JSON into Java object
3. Window events w/ fixed windows of 5 seconds
4. Using a custom `CombineFn`, combine each window of `Event`s into a `List<Event>`
5. For the sake of testing, simply output the resulting `List<Event>`

---

**Pipeline code:**

```
    pipeline
                // Read from pubsub topic to create unbounded PCollection
                .apply(PubsubIO
                    .<String>read()
                    .topic(options.getTopic())
                    .withCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())
                )

                // Deserialize JSON into Event object
                .apply("ParseEvent", ParDo
                    .of(new ParseEventFn())
                )

                // Window events with a fixed window size of 5 seconds
                .apply("Window", Window
                    .<Event>into(FixedWindows
                        .of(Duration.standardSeconds(5))
                    )
                )

                // Group events by window
                .apply("CombineEvents", Combine
                    .globally(new CombineEventsFn())
                    .withoutDefaults()
                )

                // Log grouped events
                .apply("LogEvent", ParDo
                    .of(new LogEventFn())
                );
```

---

The result we are seeing is that the final step is never run, as we don't get any logging.

Also, we have added `System.out.println("***")` in each method of our custom `CombineFn` class, in order to track when these are run, and it seems they don't run either.

Is windowing set up incorrectly here? We followed an example found at https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing and it seems fairly straightforward, but clearly there is something fundamental missing.

Any insight is appreciated - thanks in advance!

Comment: To answer your question, yes the windowing is set up correctly here. Make sure you have elements coming through Pub-Sub, by simply printing them on `ParseEventFn()`. The major thing is, did you use `pipeline.run()` to actually run the pipeline ? As you said nothing got printed.

Comment: Sorry, should have provided more context - I am already printing events in `ParseEventFn` and they are coming through - I am also using `pipeline.run()` to run the pipeline. 

I did add a trigger and this is causing the windows to emit events, which is good news - it looks like the windowing is based on event time (rather than processing time) and the windows don't know when to emit results w/o a trigger.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like the main issue was indeed a missing trigger - the window was opening and there was nothing telling it when to emit results. We wanted to simply window based on processing time (not event time) and so did the following:

```
.apply("Window", Window
    .<Event>into(new GlobalWindows())
    .triggering(Repeatedly
        .forever(AfterProcessingTime
            .pastFirstElementInPane()
            .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(5))
        )
    )
    .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO).discardingFiredPanes()
)
```

Essentially this creates a global window, which is triggered to emit events 5 seconds after the first element is processed. Every time the window is closed, another is opened once it receives an element. Beam complained when we didn't have the `withAllowedLateness` piece - as far as I know this just tells it to ignore any late data.

My understanding may be a bit off the mark here, but the above snippet has solved our problem!

Comment: What is the purpose of the 50 second windows? If the goal is just to emit data every N seconds, you should be able to use the GlobalWindow along with the processing time trigger you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks @BenChambers! That didn't seem right to me either - tried your suggestion and it works :) Will update my answer

Comment: Your windowing set up is still correct, just a different computation entirely. Do you care about events that occurred within a 5 second period? This is windowing. Do you care about getting incremental results every 5 seconds during processing of a global aggregation? This is a global window + triggering. The usual cause of your prior behavior is the watermark not advancing, which would be caused by the timestamps on the elements.

Comment: Can you confirm, why you had changed from Fixed to Global Window? Does the same solution of triggering, work also with the Fixed Window?

Comment: Would be incredibly useful if logs indicated a Window that would never close/fire..

Comment: @KennKnowles can you elaborate on "The usual cause of your prior behavior is the watermark not advancing, which would be caused by the timestamps on the elements."? I feel I'm seeing a very similar issue in a very similar pipeline attempting to use fixed windows reading from rabbitmq. What would cause the watermark to not advance from an unbounded input?

Comment: @drobert could you post a question an link to it? then we can add to the SO knowledgebase

Comment: Thanks Kenn. I asked a related-but-not-quite-the-same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58221372/what-actually-manages-watermarks-in-beam

Comment: Why the trigger by default does not emit the results? is the global window is infinit? thanks in advance