# Streaming writes to GCS using Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using apache beam 2.2.0 and trying to write to GCS from my streaming pipeline once every 10 minutes using the following code:

```java
input.apply(Window.<String>into(new GlobalWindows())
    .triggering(
            Repeatedly.forever(
                    AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
                            .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(10))
            ))
    .discardingFiredPanes())
    .apply("Write output files", TextIO.write()
            .to(baseuri + "/" + randomUUIDString())
            .withNumShards(1)
            .withSuffix(".csv")
            .withWindowedWrites());
```

I see the files getting written to the temporary directory (baseuri/UUIDString/.temp-beam-xxxxx) every 10 minutes but the writes never get finalized and written to baseuri + "/" + randomUUIDString(). Am I missing something here?

I have also attached the dataflow UI screenshot showing the "Write output files" step.[image]

Comment: Hrmm, according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/44032176/433352 global window with triggers should work.

Comment: What version of beam are you using? Can you give a dataflow job id?

Comment: @jkff 2.2.0 version. Dataflow job is is 2018-01-30_15_45_08-11661064093628692248 . It's not running at the moment though.

Comment: We're looking, thank you.

Comment: Any solution found here?