# Windowing appears to work when running on the DirectRunner, but not when running on Cloud Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to break fusion with a GroupByKey. This creates one huge window and since my job is big I'd rather start emitting.

With the direct runner using something like what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44032176/11314038) it seems to work. However, when run on Cloud Dataflow it seems to batch the GBK together and not emit output until the source nodes have "succeeded".

I'm doing a bounded/batch job. I'm extracting the contents of archive files and then writing them to gcs.

Everything works except it takes longer than I expected and cpu utilization is low. I suspect that this is due to fusion -- my hypothesis is that the extraction is fused to the write operation and so there's a pattern of extraction / higher CPU followed by less CPU because we're doing network calls and back again.

The code looks like:

```
.apply("Window",
  Window.<MyType>into(new GlobalWindows())
    .triggering(
      Repeatedly.forever(                             
        AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()                                
          .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(5))))
        .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO)
        .discardingFiredPanes()
)
.apply("Add key", MapElements...)
.apply(GroupByKey.create())
```

Locally I verify using debug logs so that I can see work is being done after the GBK. The timestamp between the first extraction finishing and the first post-GBK op usually reflects the 5s duration (or other values I change it to (1,5,10,20,30)).

On GCP I verify by looking at the pipeline structure and I can see that everything after the GBK is "not started" and the output collection of the GBK is empty ("-") while the input collection has millions of elements.

Edit:

- this is on beam v2.10.0.
- the extraction is being done by a SplittableDoFn (not sure this is relevant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the answer you referred to was for a streaming pipeline (unbounded input). For batch pipeline processing a bounded input, GroupByKey will not emit till all data for a given key has been processed. Please see [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#groupbykey) for more details.